# sqlite3 database in shared memory

Tags: python, sqlite, shared-memory

I'm trying to share an in-memory database between processes. I'm using Python's sqlite3. The idea is to create a file in `/run/shm` and use it as a database. Questions are:

1. Is that safe? In particular: do read/write locks (fcntl) work the same in shm?
2. Is that a good idea in the first place? I'd like to keep things simple and not have to create a separate database process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested fcntl (in Python) with shm files and it seems that locking works correctly. Indeed, from process point of view it is a file and OS handles everything correctly.

I'm going to keep this architecture since it is simple enough and I don't see any (major) drawbacks.